# FEDEX shipping setup

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

What does "Sandbox Mode" mean in FEDEX setup?    Also, what does "Debug" mean?  What is the difference when you answer yes vs no in both cases.  We are just setting up a new website with the community edition 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

FedEx display two possibilities for communications to their webservice. sandbox or test mode (for setup and debugging) and production mode. at fedex website you will find two types of meter numbers, one for production and one for test. for production you will receive inmediate approval for rate and track calls, but for label generation codes you must go under an approval process by fedex. for testing you can go straigth forward by login into fedex developer system. for that purpose you can follow these steps:

you must log into the fedex developer center: http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html

four steps are required-> 1- Download and read docs , 2-Develop and Test, 3-Certification (only for shipping, pickup services). 4- Move to production.

In order to receive an approval for rate services, tracking and fedex locator just go to step 4 Move to production and fill all the information that appears when you press "Get Production Key" Button.

[image]

FedEx will send you an email with your key, meter number and password.

with that information you can put it at your app.
brgds

Comment: all my testing details right, but not working, am using usa only, https://snag.gy/vVSiOQ.jpg

Comment: @Aveeva which service are you using? for domestic you must choose overnight, 2days, or similar. the best way to start is to check if tracking works. is the simplest call and you will know if the error its a configuration problem or a setup one.

Comment: actually my site for USA only. I got testing  "Account ID", "Meter Number", "Key" & "Password" from fedex, right after go to check website, its not working. where you have  i get testing details, how can i test my fedex. Pls let me know is any other things i am going to follow.

Comment: @Aveeva fedex offers testing account for rate and tracking. for shipping you must request an approval. check if the gateway is gatewaybeta.fedex.com because if not you will have production vs sandbox details.

Comment: FedEx Rate API working, How can i solve FedEx Shipping Label creation error, The error is Authentication Failed.

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox mode is for testing only. Debug adds additional logging see var directory for new log fedex.log.  It shows the request and response of each webservice call and can be very handy for troubleshooting. It does not add any additional functionality for the user though.

For details on how to configure Magento for FedEx, please see the following URL:
   http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-setup.html

Comment: My credentials correct, i have two store in single magento, store 1 display Fedex shipping cost, but store 2 not displaying shipping cost, how can i solve this issue?